# Script to rearrange files into correct folders

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, batch-processing

I have a csv file with three columns: First column has two distinct entries bad or good. Distinct entries in column 2 are learn, query and test and the third column are file path names which indicates where to find the file.

```
bad test vff/v1/room_10-to-room_19_CDFFN5D5_x_0000  
bad test vff/v1/room_10-to-room_19_BVFGFGN5D5_x_0023  
bad learn vff2/v3/room_01-to-room_02_ERTY8LOK_x_00039  
bad learn vff/v3/room_01-to-room_02_TRT8LOK_x_00210  
bad query vff/v3/room_16-to-room_08_56TCS95_y_00020  
bad query vff2/v3/room_16-to-room_08_856C6S95_y_00201  
good test person/room_44/exit_call_room__5818     
good test person/room_34/cleaning_pan__812   
good learn person/room_43/walking_in_cafe_edited__717  
good learn person/room_54/enterit_call_room__387  
good query person/room_65/talki_speech_cry__1080  
good query person/room_75/walking_against_wall__835
```

Using this csv, I wanted to create three folders based oncolumn 2. So basically, use column 2 to create three folders namely test, learn and query. Within each of these 3 folders, I want to create two folders i.e.bad and good based on column 1. Then be able to pull the data using column3 andplace the respective files in these defined folders. Is there a  python or command linescript that can do this?

Comment: You say ```csv``` which means "Comma separated values" but the values in your example seem to be separated by spaces. What is the delimiter you want your information to be separated with?

Comment: _Is there a  python or command linescript that can do this?_ I'm sure there is, somewhere in the Aether. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this csv file is named `file.csv`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FILE="file.csv"

# Create direcory structure
for C2 in `cat ${FILE} | cut -f 2 -d ',' | sort -u`
do
    for C1 in `cat ${FILE} | cut -f 1 -d ',' | sort -u`
    do
        mkdir -p "${C2}/${C1}"
    done
done

# Move files
while IFS= read -r line
do
    file="$(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ',' | tr -d ' ')"
    dir="$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d ',' | tr -d ' ')"
    dir+="/$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d ',')"
    mv "${file}" "${dir}"
done < "${FILE}"
```

Some things that are happening in this `bash` script:

1. `cut` This command is very usefull for selecting the `n'th` item from a `delimiter` separated list. In this instance we are working with a `csv` so you will see `cut -d ','` to specify a comma as a delimiter.
2. Creating the directory structure: Column 2 is the *parent* directory and Column 1 is the *child* directory, thus the `cut -f 2` list is the outer for loop and `cut -f 1` is the inner for loop
3. `sort -u` removes repeated occurrences of a string. This allows us to iterate through all the *different* entries for a given column
4. Moving the files: Every line in `file.csv` contains a file that needs to be move, thus the iteration through each line in the file. Then the directory we created earlier is extracted from Columns 2 and 1 and the file is moved to it's new home